# leading and paragraph-style footnotes

Tags: footnotes, line-spacing

This is a follow-up to [leading package and vertical space between footnotes](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/61859/7883).  Werner’s answer works beautifully, but not with the `para` option of `footmisc`.  Is there a way to make the line-spacing of footnotes consistent when adjusting the leading of a font and using paragraph-style footnotes?

Here is an example of the problem:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[norule,para]{footmisc}
\linespread{1.15}
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61908/7883
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makefntext}
  {#1}
  {\usebox\strutbox#1}
  {}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the
bank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into
the book her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or
conversations in it.\footnote{`And what is the use of a book,' thought
  Alice `without pictures or conversation?'}

So she was considering in her own mind\footnote{As well as she could,
  for the hot day made her feel very sleepy and stupid.} whether the
pleasure of making a daisy-chain would be worth the trouble of getting
up and picking the daisies, when suddenly a White Rabbit with pink
eyes ran close by her.

There was nothing so \textsc{very} remarkable in that; nor did Alice
think it so \textsc{very} much out of the way to hear the Rabbit say
to itself, `Oh dear!  Oh dear!  I shall be late!';\footnote{When she
  thought it over afterwards, it occurred to her that she ought to
  have wondered at this, but at the time it all seemed quite natural.}
but when the Rabbit actually \textsc{took a watch out of its
  waistcoat-pocket}, and looked at it, and then hurried on, Alice
started to her feet, for it flashed across her mind that she had never
before seen a rabbit with either a waistcoat-pocket, or a watch to
take out of it, and burning with curiosity, she ran across the field
after it, and fortunately was just in time to see it pop down a large
rabbit-hole under the hedge.

In another moment down went Alice after it, never once considering how
in the world she was to get out again.
\end{document}
```

[image: detail of the output]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think you need the redefinition from the earlier question. But be that as it may, here is what seems to be the issue:

1. Footmisc sets the linespacing in footnotes based on the value that the `baselineskip` for `footnotesize` text had when `footmisc` was loaded. That means that your footnotes are being set as if `\linespread` was 1, because when the package is loaded you haven't made the change.
2. Footmisc inserts a `\strut` at the point where it makes the footnote marker. This is having the effect of increasing the space in lines where there is a footnotemarker, because the `\strut` is set for a baselineskip that *has* been adjusted by reference to your linespread.

So what you are seeing is the result of setting the footnote paragraphs with a `linespread` of 1, but with a `\strut` appropriate to a `linespread` of 1.3 at the start of each individual footnote. That throws the spacing off completely.

There are two things you can do:

1. If you *want* single-spaced footnotes, then leave things as they are, but patch footmisc so that it doesn't insert the problematic `\strut`

   ```
   \patchcmd{\@footnotetext}
     {\strut}
     {}
     {}{}
   ```

   I suppose that ideally one would actually insert a rule with the proper dimensions for single-spaced footnotesize text: but in practical terms you will probably survive without anything.
2. If you want your footnotes to have the same line spacing adjustment, make sure you issue your `\linespread` *before* loading footmisc.

Complete MWE below:

```
\documentclass[12pt]{book}
\usepackage[a5paper]{geometry}
\linespread{1.3}%<- Put here to have spaced footnote text
\usepackage[norule,para]{footmisc}
%\linespread{1.3}%<- Put here to have single spaced footnotes
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/61908/7883
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@footnotetext}
  {\strut}
  {}
  {}{}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

Alice was beginning to get very tired of sitting by her sister on the
bank, and of having nothing to do: once or twice she had peeped into
the book her sister was reading, but it had no pictures or
conversations in it.\footnote{`And what is the use of a book,' thought
  Alice `without pictures or conversation?'}

So she was considering in her own mind\footnote{As well as she could,
  for the hot day made her feel very sleepy and stupid.} whether the
pleasure of making a daisy-chain would be worth the trouble of getting
up and picking the daisies, when suddenly a White Rabbit with pink
eyes ran close by her.

There was nothing so \textsc{very} remarkable in that; nor did Alice
think it so \textsc{very} much out of the way to hear the Rabbit say
to itself, `Oh dear!  Oh dear!  I shall be late!';\footnote{When she
  thought it over afterwards, it occurred to her that she ought to
  have wondered at this, but at the time it all seemed quite natural.}
but when the Rabbit actually \textsc{took a watch out of its
  waistcoat-pocket}, and looked at it, and then hurried on, Alice
started to her feet, for it flashed across her mind that she had never
before seen a rabbit with either a waistcoat-pocket, or a watch to
take out of it, and burning with curiosity, she ran across the field
after it, and fortunately was just in time to see it pop down a large
rabbit-hole under the hedge.

In another moment down went Alice after it, never once considering how
in the world she was to get out again.
\end{document}
```

**Spaced Version**

[image: spaced version]

**Unspaced Version**

[image]

Comment: Thank you!  This works not only with my little example but with my big and complicated real case.