how to get consistent linespacing between footnotes when using linespread (I know of setspace, but this is not an option)?
I use KOMASkript classes (but I also experience the problem with the standard classes): When I set the linespread greater 1 (in my example \linespread{1.09}) the baselineskip from one footnote to the next footnote does not seem to change correctly. The space between lines in one (big, multiple lines spanning) footnote is correct. However, from the last line of the first footnote to the first line of the next footnote, the space seems to be too small. Here is an example with a big value for \linespread to show what I mean:
Example:
\documentclass{scrartcl}


\usepackage{newpx}

\linespread{1.8}

\newcommand{\test}{This is only nonsens text for testing purposes. }


\begin{document}
This%
\footnote{%
    \test\test\test\test
}
is a test.%
\footnote{%
    \test\test\test\test
}
\test\test\test\test\test\test
\end{document}

I don't like the result: See the picture:

Does anybody have an idea how to get consistent spacing between footnotes?
PS: I use lualatex (but I also tested with pdflatex and had the same problem).
And one additional point: I don't want to use the setspace package. Because as far as I know, it only adjusts the baselineskip in the normal body text. However, I also want to have a little bit more space in the footnotes. Because I think the font looks to cramped with the standard baselineskip.
EDIT:
Thanks @DavidCarlisle for pointing me at \SetSinglespace, iI have never heared of this (is it even documented?). I like it, because it also effects the spacing of footnotes. However, my initial problem still persists; even with \SetSinglespace. So multiple lines in one footnote are appropriately spaced, but the space from one footnote to the next footnote is still to small. There must be some way to achieve consistent linespacing between footnotes(?)
Interesting, I just found a similar question here. As I understand from one of the comments of @RuixiZhang, the package forgets to update \footnotesep:

Ehhh, setspace also forgets to update \footnotesep via
\footnotesep\setspace@singlespace\footnotesep, which causes the
separation between footnotes unmatched with the stretched line
spacing. I guess the author(s) didn’t foresee that someone would
actually change \setspace@singlespace from unity.

2nd EDIT:
Thanks @Thérèse for pointing me at this question (and its precursor). As far as I can see, this should solve my problem.

Welcome to TeX.SE!

Quote from the koma script manual: "In the worst case, use the \linespread command. I recommend the package setspace (see [TF11])"

@samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz thank you for the tip! However, this is not an option for me, because I want to have additional space between the lines (also in the footnotes). Because I think the font (Palatino clone) looks to cramped with standard line spacing (I think it also says in the KOMASkript manual).

\linespread is just for local emergency corrections it sets the baseline at that point but that will be lost at any font change. you would do better with \renewcommand\baselinestretch{1.8} or better still with setspace

@DavidCarlisle oh ok, I didn't know, thank you for the hint. But as far as I know, setspace only offers onehalfspacing and doublespacing, which are both too much (I deliberately chose the \linespread{1.8} to make the effects more obvious in my example; however, in the real document I only have \linespread{1.09}, so only a small increase). And I want to have this slightly additional space between the lines also in the footnotes. And setspace does not adjust the spacing in footnotes as far sas I know(?).

no setspace gives a spacing command to allow any value

setspace sets footnotes with the baslineskip scaled by the value set by \SetSinglespace so you probably want to use setspace singlespace along with \SetSinglespace{1.1} or whatever

Does https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/185922 help you?

@Thérèse Thank you this is exactly what I was looking for!

Thanks @DavidCarlisle and @Thérèse for pointing me in the right direction.
I basicly made up two possible solutions: Both start by using \SetSinglespace{<Factor>} rather than using \linespread{<Factor>}. Both solutions only differ in the way how consistent line spacing between footnotes is ensured. The first solution seems to update the \footnotesep(?) while the second solution patches \@makefntext using etoolbox.
Solution 1: (based on this discussion)
\documentclass{scrartcl}


\usepackage{newpx}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}


\SetSinglespace{1.09}
\singlespacing

\makeatletter
\footnotesep\setspace@singlespace\footnotesep
\makeatother

\newcommand{\test}{This is only nonsens text for testing purposes. }


\begin{document}
This%
\footnote{%
    \test\test\test\test
}
is a test.%
\footnote{%
    \test\test\test\test
}
\test\test\test\test\test\test
\end{document}

Solution2: (based on this discussion)
\documentclass{scrartcl}


\usepackage{newpx}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[nodisplayskipstretch]{setspace}


\SetSinglespace{1.09}
\singlespacing    

\newcommand{\test}{This is only nonsens text for testing purposes. }

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@makefntext}% <cmd>
  {#1}% <search>
  {\usebox\strutbox#1}% <replace>
  {}{}% <success><failure>
\makeatother


\begin{document}
This%
\footnote{%
    \test\test\test\test
}
is a test.%
\footnote{%
    \test\test\test\test
}
\test\test\test\test\test\test
\end{document}

